# Como capturar a lista de membros de um grupo privado ou secreto do Facebook utilizando a GRAPH API?

Tags: facebook, api

Tenho um grupo no Facebook como aberto e utilizo o seguinte metodo para retornar uma array com todos os membros do grupo:

```
$group_members = $this->facebook->api("/id_do_grupo/members");
```

Quando altero o grupo para privado ou secreto a array retorna vazia. Não deveria, pois sou membro do grupo e obviamente estou autenticado no app para usar o facebook->api.

Comment: Seu aplicativo pede a permissão `user_groups` quando faz a conexão?

Comment: Não estava pedindo, porém adicionei, limpei o cache do browsers, fiz o login novamente, autorizei o user_groups e continua exibindo uma array vazia quando está como grupo fechado.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo minhas pesquisas tive a seguinte resposta:

Você pode acessar as permissões de usuário e amigos. Há uma permissão user_groups específica. Geralmente o modo de autenticação como o Facebook funciona é que o usuário da autenticação irá permitir a sua aplicação ou (website) o acesso. Então, se um usuário é membro de um grupo particular e permite que seu aplicativo se conecte através da permissão user_groups, seu aplicativo se conectará com sucesso.

Inglês -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399333/get-access-token-for-a-closed-group-on-facebook-graph-api

Doc -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions